# How to extract jpegs from a video file using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am using C# and ffmpeg.

In this scenario I have 279 individual jpegs and i have used ffmpeg to create a AVI file from these images on my client.

CMD Line:

```
 -f image2 -r 10 -i "C:\000EC902F17F\img%05d.jpg"  -s 352x288  -y "C:\1\test.avi"
```

I then upload to my server.

CMD Line:

```
-i c:\1\1.avi c:\1\img-%05d.jpg
```

I then extract jpegs from the AVI file. I get 265 jpegs back.

Obviously ffmpeg is dropping these frames (most probable) when the avi is 1st created.  Is there a way to 'force' to encode using ALL the images I have?

Thanks.

PS
I did not specify any command line option other than the size of the video output.  As far as I am aware if none are specified then ffmpeg automatically chooses the best ones?

Comment: I found the answer.  There is a FPS input and output.  As you can see I have -r 10 (which is 10 frames per second).  All I needed to do was add -r 10 after the -y to force it to encode frame for frame

Comment: To clarify, by default if an input `-r` is not declared then ffmpeg will use `-r 25` for the input (and therefore output). If you only declare an output `-r`, then ffmpeg will have drop or duplicate frames to go from 25 to match your output `-r`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard HI, thanks for extra info.  Appreciated..

Comment: out of interest would setting it to 1 fps make it slower or faster than if i set it to say 10 fps? Or not make any difference. I am referring to the time it takes to encode all the images rather than the playback tempo..

Comment: If you only set an input frame rate of `-r 1` then the output will also be `-r 1`. I guess `-r 10` would encoder faster than `-r 1`, but the difference may not be significant.

Comment: OK, I shall do some testing and post back. thanks for replying..